# Transfer of Description and Image using Segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am currently trying to create a map app that has around 20 pins. I have made a segue so that the Pin's Annotation's  Title is transferred. However now I need to implement it so that a description is correctly selected from a series of 20 .txt file descriptions and 20 images. But I believe I am able to do it with one Segue.

Here is my current code

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController,    MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var MapView: MKMapView!
let manager = CLLocationManager()
var artworkPin:Artwork!

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    //let location = locations[0]


    //let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.02, 0.02)

    //let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)


}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // tracking user's location
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    // Setting up Map
    let distanceSpan:CLLocationDegrees = 2000
    MapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.0556253, 174.0752278), distanceSpan, distanceSpan), animated: true)
    MapView.showsUserLocation = true
    MapView.delegate = self

    // artwork on map
    let windwandcoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.055961,174.072288)
    artworkPin = Artwork(title:"Wind Wand",locationName:"Majestic",discipline:"Statue",
                             coordinate:windwandcoord)
    MapView.addAnnotation(artworkPin)

}


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
{
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {return nil}

    let reuseId = "pin"

    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
        pinView!.animatesDrop = true
        pinView!.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
        let calloutButton = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = calloutButton
        pinView!.sizeToFit()
    }
    else {
        pinView!.annotation = annotation
    }


    return pinView
}



func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "no", sender:self)
    }
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


    let ViewTwo = segue.destination as! ViewTwo
    ViewTwo.artworkPin = self.artworkPin
}


}
```

I also don't think this will give the correct title if I add another pin am I correct? Because it will simply take the name of **artworkPin** rather than of any variable pin added.

Thanks for any help.